# Can I receive a bluetooth signal from a paired arduino into an android app even when the phone is not being used?(like saved in the pocket)

Tags: java, android, arduino

So, basically I want to trigger an action in an app by using an arduino with a Bluetooth module.
The idea is that once that the arduino has been connected with the phone, I might be able to trigger actions in the app even when the phone isn’t being used and is saved in your pocket for example.

Is that possible? And if so, how can I do the code in the app? Like if it is just waiting for a message? 
Thanks for the attention guys.

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect the two devices, you should be able to set up a listener on the Android device to listen for incoming data from the Arduino. Take a closer look at how you can do this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#connect). Also, take a look at how to [receive notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#notification). You *should* still get notifications even when the device is sleeping, but I'd set it up and give it a try to be sure.

Hope that helps!